# SQL Repeate or Duplicate results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a report that need a duplicate of the information in order to generate 2 sheets (original and copy).

So I would like to know how to do it considering the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
emp.name,
emp.lastname,
emp.birthdate,
emp.gender
FROM employee emp
WHERE employeeid = 1
```

> The above query will just through 1 result (1 Row) and I need the same information to be duplicated so I have 2 rows.

One way to do that is to do a `UNION ALL` with the same query like:

```
SELECT 
    emp.name,
    emp.lastname,
    emp.birthdate,
    emp.gender
    FROM employee emp
    WHERE employeeid = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    emp.name,
    emp.lastname,
    emp.birthdate,
    emp.gender
    FROM employee emp
    WHERE employeeid = 1
```

But I don't like to repeate the query.

> Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similiar logic to Jaaz Cole, but it shouldn't matter what SQL flavour you have.  Simple logic, join the table to a 2 row set...it'll bring back 2 of each row.

```
SELECT 
emp.name,
emp.lastname,
emp.birthdate,
emp.gender
FROM employee emp
inner join (select 1 as a union all select 2) a on 1 = 1
WHERE employeeid = 1
```

Honestly I think it'd be easier to replicate two sheets on the sheet level instead of the data level like this...seems a bit odd in practice to me at any rate.

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` would be a better join operator in this case.

Comment: @ElectricLlama - inner join on 1 = 1 and cross join are the same statement really.  I guess using the word cross join instead of inner join means you don't need the 1=1 part.

Comment: `Inner join` implies you actually want to join. `cross join` clearly means you want a cross product. I guess to me the intention is self-documenting and more evident. If you want a cross product use a cross join, not an inner join with a dummy join operator. Everyone does things differently though.

Answer (score 0):

This is only going to work for SQL Server 2005+ (you didn't tag a version on your question), but should duplicate your results quickly with a constant scan.

```
SELECT 
    emp.name,
    emp.lastname,
    emp.birthdate,
    emp.gender
FROM employee emp
    CROSS APPLY ( SELECT 1 AS R UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS R) N
WHERE employeeid = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here CROSS JOIN which I though I would add since I spammed everyone else.

```
SELECT 
N.R,
emp.name,
emp.lastname,
emp.birthdate,
emp.gender
FROM employee emp
CROSS JOIN( SELECT 1 AS R UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS R) N
WHERE emp.employeeid = 1
```